# Android: TV remote control from Android device

Tags: android, sdk, television

I have a TV (Samsung Tizen, LG Web OS) and an Android device (tablet, phone). They are connected to the same Wi-Fi network. I want to send a command from the Android device to the TV which will switch, for example, the HDMI ports.

About TV: I only know the IP-address.

What I tried so far: I investigated ChromeCast and ConnectSDK. But I don't need to share any information from my phone. I am only looking to need switch HDMI ports.

Can you help me please? How can I do this?

Comment: Try using p2p connection, It will enable de cellphon-tv communication. Look for wifi-direct and p2p conneections

Answer (score 0):

Cast SDK does not have any API for controlling HDMI inputs.